# Unable to understand the structure of the array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database and I want to retrieve column names and their values in php to load them into jquery-datatable. When I `print_r($row)` after the `$row=$query->fetchAll()` I can see the output of print_r as:

```
           Array ( [0] => Array ( [d_id] => 20160317 [0] => 20160317 [lid] => 1 [1] => 1 [la_val] => 23.094123 [2] => 23.094123 [lo_val] => 37.607672 [3] => 37.607672 [ctime] => 15:10 [4] => 15:10 [tmp_c] => 28.2 [5] => 28.2 [colour] => 90 [6] => 90).
```

I have been able to retrieve the column name by using:

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename");
    $query->execute();
    $row=$query->fetchAll();
    print_r($row);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $query->columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $query->getColumnMeta($i);
        $columns[] = $col['name'];
        print_r($columns[$i]." "); // d_id lid la_val lo_val
```

But further, I am not able to understand the array structure.

Comment: Add `echo '<pre>';` prior `print_r()`

Comment: Oh, Thats great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is two dimensional. The outer array has a numeric index, which represents the record (as you called `fetchAll()`, you can get multiple rows). The inner array is actually a combination of two: One uses the column number as the key, the other uses the column name. This is because the default option for `fetch()` and `fetchAll()` is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which is equivalent to `PDO::FETCH_NUM | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. So you get each column value twice, with different array keys.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I could look at the array and understand more about it. But is it possible to get back the data only once, with 1 key-value pair rather than getting to see twice with different array keys?

Comment: Yes, use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick help. :)